# Angular: Disabling/Enabling a button in a component not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a component that emits an event when a checkbox is clicked. This particular component is inside another component with a button, which needs to be disabled at first and it should be enabled when someone checks the checkboxes. This component is in a ngFor. So there will be a couple of components with checkboxes and a button.

Checking a checkbox is enabling all the buttons of other components as well. I am not sure why this is happening. Any one had this before?

The component looks like this

```html
<app-group [selection]="selection" (filterChanged)="onFilterChange()" >
</app-group>
<div *ngIf="ifCondition">
  <button (click)="save()" [disabled]="disableSaveBtn">
      <span>Save</span>
  </button>
```

The parent component looks like this

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index">
    <app-savable-group (filterChanged)="onFilterChange($event)">
    </app-savable-group>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You need to give an index which of the index it is checked.
At the *ngFor="let example of examples; let i = index" and then on click or check method you pass the index of the element and then in ts you make as checked this element.

Comment: Can you reproduce the scenario at Stackblitz?